# how to make argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter not collapse consecutive empty lines

Tags: python

Python manuals say that `argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter` assumes that my help message is already correctly formatted and preserves all whitespace.

Not true - if I have multiple consecutive empty lines, it still collapses them to a single empty line.

How do I really make it not touch *any* of my formatting?

The example, as simple as I can make it.  You can see that it correctly preserves weird indentation, but it does not preserve multiple empty lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from argparse import *

ArgumentParser(
  formatter_class = RawTextHelpFormatter,
  usage='''
      start



  end
  ''').parse_args()
```

produces

```
> ./foobar.py -h
usage:
      start

  end
```

(...)

Comment: If you show us a sample program that exhibits this behavior, it would make it easier to help.

Comment: @merlin2011 well, my intent, was to find someone who will already have known the answer, and would say "this is what is happening".  My intent was not to have people spend their valuable time help me debug this.  But OK if you wish :)

Comment: I appreciate your thoughtfulness, but I think it's generally better to give people *more* options than less. :)

Comment: @merlin2011 right you are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand why this is happening. But I would add single space to each line.
Adding one space to middle one is sufficient.
(Of course, it's only partial fix - but who cares about one space?)

(I tried to post this code here, but StackOverflow erases these spaces anyway)